# Can we create the controls using Scriptaculous.js and prototype.js or this library is for giving the effects on control

Tags: scriptaculous

I am New for the technology.
I want to know that "Can we create the controls using scriptaculous.js and prototype.js or this library is for giving the effects,Drag n Drop,Auto Completer?." Because i have seen in dojo.js they have their own controls as we create in dojo.(Button,CheckBox etc...)

I want to know about which is the best library to used for Effects,Animation etc.
(scriptaculous.js,prototype.js vs dojo.js vs jQuery vs YUI).

Please comment on it.

Regards,
Mauunusanghi

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you be more clear about your overall objective/specification? What would be your metric for defining the "best" library?

Comment: Hi Dave ...
I want to know that can scriptaculous.js or prototype.js provides the own controls like (CommandButton,CheckButton,RadioButton,Grid,TextField,DateControl,CalenderControl,TabPane,TabAccordions) etc.... So many controls which used frequently while developing the web application.
Or we have to use Html controls. because dojo provides the own controls with rich look.

Please suggest me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create controls using prototype. You'd typically be using [Element.insert](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/insert). You can also use all scriptaculous/prototype functions on the newly created element.

The "which is best" question is answered elsewhere on SO.

Comment: Thanks krosenvold for your answer...

Can you please send me the link where i can read the best document for scriptaculous.js and prototype.js. I already know that they have their own sites but if other sites have good tutorials where i can learn as quickly as possible will help me.

Comment: Please suggest me which IDE is best suitable for using scriptaculous.js and prototype.js.

Comment: I think the website http://www.prototypejs.org/ has fairly good examples. Personally I use Intellij Idea, which has fabulous javascript support